# how to create MYSQL prepare statements and resetting them in 1 stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I currently am looping through a list of userNames from the DB. as such :

```
DECLARE
    cur1 CURSOR FOR
        select user_name
           from users
          where user_type = 'SP'
          and active = 'Y';

OPEN cur1;

read_loop : LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO userName;
```

Now for each userName, i am creating tables with data. Obviously, within the above LOOP, i have multiple PREPARE statements like :

```
   set l_table_name = concat("tmp_rec_",userName);

   set l_select_cnt = concat("SELECT count(1) into @l_cnt
                               from information_schema.tables
                              where table_schema = 'greptlat_db'
                              and table_name = '", l_table_name, "'");
   PREPARE stmt2 FROM @l_select_cnt;
   EXECUTE stmt2;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

   if l_cnt > 0 then
       set droptable = concat("drop table ", l_table_name);

       PREPARE stmt1 FROM @droptable;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
   END IF;
```

I have more PREPARE statements that build the data that i want and inserts it into the table that i create for each user.

Now because this is in a LOOP, for each user, i have read that PREPARE statements are global. Which means, the above code, "PREPARE stmt1 FROM @droptable", stmt1 will never change even though it gors through the LOOP for each user. Even if i DEALLOCATE it, it still remains for that stored procedure.

How can i reset this stmt1,stmt2,stmt3 ...etc for each time the LOOP starts again ?

Basically l_table_name will change for each time the LOOP goes through, but stmt1 doesnt change.. I need stmt1 to change so that it will use the new l_table_name everytime

Answer (score 0):

Normally a prepare statement deallocated implicitly before the new statement is prepared. So what is the result if you remove `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;`. Did you check the '@droptable' value in each loop?

Comment: Yes, i checked the @droptable, and it doesnt have the correct l_table_name ..however if i just output l_table_name variable itself, it is correct

Comment: Did you tried without DEALLOCATE. what is the result. Remove all DEALLOCATE, because to get proper stmt1 first you have to genereate stmt2 properly. So remove all DEALLOCATE and try.